# Laravel decrement column value but not negative

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, laravel-5

I know i can reduce the column value in laravel using this query

```
DB::table('users')->decrement('votes', 5);
```

But i want to restrict the value from being become negative value.

Is there anyway to do this with laravel?

Comment: declare votes field in migration as unsignedInteger i.e $table->unsignedInteger('votes');

Comment: Thanks @BalrajAllam for the reply. But i have a small question. Above code will return _false_ in this case?

Comment: no, it simply does not allow negative values in the votes column.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You'll need to use raw queries for that.

The following code should do the trick for all DB engines that support **GREATEST** function:

```
DB::table('users')->update(['votes' => DB::raw('GREATEST(votes - 5, 0)')]);
```

It will decrement **votes** column in **users** table by 5, but won't go below zero - that's what **GREATEST** function is used for.

Answer (score 2):

If you really want to use decrement in this case (could be handy if you're accessing it through a relationship for example), you could do something like:

`$thing->decrement('votes', $thing->votes - $amount <= 0 ? $thing->votes : $amount);`

Where `$amount` is 5 in your case. It's pretty ugly in my opinion. Worth noting if you already have $thing (say via a relationship) it won't trigger an additional query when accessing votes.

If you are only incrementing by 1, a simply `if` wrapped around is cleaner:

```
        if($thing->votes > 0) {
            $thing->decrement('votes');
        }
```